# blazor wasm read asp.net culture cookie at startup

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm setting the culture cookie like this:

```
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync(
            "site.setCookie", 
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName, 
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo(name))));
```

which will set the `.AspNetCore.Culture` cookie

and in `Blazor Server` in Startup/Program.cs I would call:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization
```

which will make it automatically read the ASP.net Culture Cookie and set the `CurrentCulture`;

`UseRequestLocalization` doesn't seem to be available in `Blazor WASM`,

how are we supposed to do this here, is there something built-in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly#localization

The culture needs to be set manually in in Program.cs before calling `app.RunAsync()`:

```
var app = builder.Build();

var js = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
var result = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");

if (result != null)
{
    var culture = new CultureInfo(result);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
}

await app.RunAsync();
```

and we're getting it using js, not automatically from something like `Response.Cookies`